# How to import C assert in cpp20 experimental

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, c++-modules

I'd like to use the C [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) with C++20 in Visual Studio 2019 (compiling with `std:c++latest`), but I couldn't find the correct module to import. Is it already supported and if yes, which module I should import?

```
import std.core;
constexpr auto f()
{
    return "Hello world!";
}
int main()
{
    static_assert(f() == "Hello world!"); // Compile time assert works.
    //assert(f() == "Hello world!"); // How to import runtime assert()?
    //[[assert: f() == "Hello world!"]] // Contracts were removed from cpp20.
    std::cout << f();
}
```

Output: Hello world!

Answer (score 4):

Modules do not contain macros. Importing legacy module headers will bring in macros, but `import std.core;` or whatever never will bring in a macro.

Answer (score 3):

Modules can be used side by side with header files. A C++ source file can import modules and also #include header files. I suggest you could try to add `#include <assert.h>`

Comment: Valid, but be careful: This works in the sequence include header first, then import the module `#include <assert.h> \n import std.core;`. The other way around it causes compiler errors, since the macros inside e.g `corecrt.h` are not evaluated by the preprocessor (at least currently in VisualStudio).